# How can I output blank value in python yaml file

Tags: python, yaml, pyyaml

I am writing yaml file like this

```
with open(fname, "w") as f:
     yaml.safe_dump({'allow':'', 'deny': ''}, f,
                    default_flow_style=False, width=50, indent=4)
```

This outputs:

```
allow: ''
```

I want to output as

```
allow:
```

How can I do that?

Comment: you basically want to set it as null instead of an empty string?

Comment: You're asking how to save a different value than the actual data? Why? If the actual data is an empty string, so should be the yaml representation of that data, shouldn't it? Have you tried setting the original values to `None`?

Comment: @BryanOakley , if i put None , then it display null in yaml . i want to keep it blank. i am hard coding value . i was looking for variable which i can use in actual value to give blank output like null , None etc. i didn't want to use replace

Comment: In YAML a blank value is interpreted as null, so whats the differance? Just use `None`. It will get interpreted the same way. Unless, of course, there is some very specific reason you need it to be blank regardless of how it is interpreted. In which case you might want to let us know so we can help with that. Perhaps knowing the context of your request, someone could suggest a different way to get what you want.

Comment: @Waylan IN all yaml files i have seen for config ,  the if key is usually empty then is blank not `(null or None or '')` so i just want to create file  like that so that if i want to write something then i don't need to delete those un required characters

Comment: use `allow: null`

In python, `allow: ''` need not work properly all the time.


As per python __ZEN__ : "Explicit is always better than implicit"

Answer (score 93):

For `None` type to be read from python use `null` in yaml

A YAML file `test.yml` like this

```
foo: null
bar: null
```

will be read by python as

```
import yaml
test = yaml.load(open('./test.yml'))
print(test)

foo: None
bar: None
```

Comment: This is true, but not what the OP asked for.

Answer (score 20):

```
from yaml import SafeDumper
import yaml

data = {'deny': None, 'allow': None}

SafeDumper.add_representer(
    type(None),
    lambda dumper, value: dumper.represent_scalar(u'tag:yaml.org,2002:null', '')
  )

with open('./yadayada.yaml', 'w') as output:
  yaml.safe_dump(data, output, default_flow_style=False)
```

There is a way to do this built into python yaml itself. The above code will produce a file containing:

```
allow:
deny:
```

Comment: I think this should be the correct answer. Seems like the cleanest solution that appropriately addresses this question with the library's proper internals.

Comment: Perfect! You saved my day

Answer (score 12):

If you load a YAML src

```
allow:
```

into Python you get `None` assigned to the key `allow`, that is the correct behaviour.

If you use [ruamel.yaml](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ruamel.yaml) (of which I am the author), and its `RoundTripDumper`, `None` is written as you want it (which is IMO the most readable, although not explicit):

```
import ruamel.yaml

print ruamel.yaml.dump(dict(allow=None), Dumper=ruamel.yaml.RoundTripDumper)
```

will give you:

```
allow:
```

You can also properly round-trip this:

```
import ruamel.yaml

yaml_src = """
allow:
key2: Hello  # some test

"""

data = ruamel.yaml.load(yaml_src, ruamel.yaml.RoundTripLoader)
print('#### 1')
print(data['allow'])
print('#### 2')
print(ruamel.yaml.dump(data, Dumper=ruamel.yaml.RoundTripDumper))

print('#### 3')

print(type(data))
```

to get as output:

```
#### 1
None
#### 2
allow:
key2: Hello  # some test


#### 3
<class 'ruamel.yaml.comments.CommentedMap'>
```

In the above, `data` is a subclass of ordereddict, which is necessary to keep track of the flowstyle of the input, handling comments attached to lines, order of the keys, etc..
Such a subclass can be created on the fly, but it is normally easier to start with some readable and well formatted YAML code (possible already saved on disc) and then update/extend the values.

Answer (score 6):

Using replace, this seems straightforward:

```
import yaml

fname = 'test.yaml'
with open(fname, "w") as f:
    yaml_str = yaml.safe_dump({'allow':'', 'deny': ''},
                            default_flow_style=False,
                            width=50, 
                            indent=4).replace(r"''", '')
    f.write(yaml_str)
```

Is there a reason why you want to avoid `replace`?

There is the drawback that re-loading the yaml file does not reproduce your input:

```
>>> print yaml.safe_load(open(fname))
{'deny': None, 'allow': None}
```